# Android libgdx IAP billing?

Tags: android, libgdx

I need to use this library:

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

and I have a libgdx AndroidLiveWallpaperService

the probleme I don't know how to implement it, because it is for Activity and not for AndroidLiveWallpaperService. I have a LiveWallpaper class to that extends AndroidLiveWallpaperService, but I can't figure it out how to add onActivityresult to that.

Is it any IAP billing lib for libgdx and live wallpapers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [gdx-pay](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay), libGDX cross-platform API for InApp purchasing. It provide a cross-platform API for InApp purchasing.

**EDIT**

May be If you're not able to integrate LWP with gdx-pay, You can use

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Comment: I trying with gdx pay but no working example at the moment. It give me always " no purchase manager found." Can you help me?

Comment: please show me your build.gradle file. According to me you're not injecting **gdx-pay-client** artifact. PurchaseManager is available in gdx-pay-client

Comment: dependencies {
    compile files('libs/gdx.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-backend-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-freetype.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-bullet.jar')
    compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'

    compile files('libs/gdx-pay-android-0.10.3-library.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-pay-android-googleplay-0.10.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-pay-0.10.3-library.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-pay-client-0.10.3-library.jar')
}

Comment: maybe I have to upload the signed apk first to the play console in beta mode? and than the purchase manager will be available after install from beta from google play??

Comment: why don't you configure dependency by Gradle instead of manual configuration. Recommended way to use gdx-pay via Gradle or Maven and  Artifacts are available in maven central repository.

Comment: It looks like the gdx pay not working at the moment with live wallpapers. So I had to use in app billing v3. It is work like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got your solution. Actually i was integrated only with Application not LWP.